# Import-StartLayout does nothing for current user

Tags: powershell, windows-10, startmenu

Using the command as follows:

```
Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Blank_Layout.xml" -MountPath "C:\"
```

Unfortunately does not change the current Start Menu layout. It creates a new file under `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml`, and it is blank.

I'm hoping that is because I intended the layout to be blank, I also had to grant permissions to that folder to run the command in the first place.

The information I used came from [Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2016/03/07/windows-10-start-layout-customization/), I do know that this can be pushed via GPO and added to an image, but that is not the intended goal for now.

Comment: From my understanding it is not meant to affect the current user. Why would you want it too anyway. You do not want to make changes to an existing users profile as that would be potentially breaking.

Comment: Its part of our pre-deployment process before the device goes to the user. I did come across this topic which led me to some batch files and other research another user has done. https://superuser.com/questions/1117136/import-startlayout-doesnt-change-anything

Comment: I'll see if their solutions work and post what I did here as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This batch script worked for me, I'm in the process of converting it to a powershell script. Got it working but with a few errors. But the batch version worked 100% with no issues.

It can be found here:
[GitHub](https://github.com/TurboLabIt/StartTileBackup)